# Windows 10 blue screen instead of background image

Tags: windows-10, lock-screen, background

so I have Windows 10 Pro and I configured an image to all cases (Background image, lock screen, etc).

But from time to time when I come back to my PC after a night I didn't touch it, I see a blue screen on my lock screen instead of my background image:

[image]

Here are my personal configurations:
Background: 
[image]
Lock Screen:
[image]

So what am I missing? Thanks.

Comment: How big is that file? Maybe use tinypng on it?

Comment: @Gantendo about 300KB

Comment: Did you try simply debugging, such as setting a different image, then going back?

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for related messages.

Comment: @Destroy666 Same with 3 different images...
harrymc - no events related in the Event Viewer.

Comment: You could try classic `dism` + `sfc`. Do you use any apps that could interfere with lock screen?

Comment: How do I know which apps interfere with the lock screen?
I leave the browser open.. maybe it's related?
It usually happens when I am away from my pc for 8-10+ hours. Less than that - It shows the image.